# Adding Migrations to a Database in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to asp.net MVC 4,
and after creating a database in SQL server, i've added an Entity Data Model to my project in Visual Studio (creating it using the existing Database). Now i want to add Migrations to my project but it's not working.

I tried the following:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -Force
More than one context type was found in the assembly 'SGR.frontOffice'.
To enable migrations for 'SGR.frontOffice.Database.SGRDb', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName SGR.frontOffice.Database.SGRDb.
To enable migrations for 'SGR.frontOffice.EF.Entities', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName SGR.frontOffice.EF.Entities.
```

And then i did:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName SGR.frontOffice.EF.Entities -Force
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715
   at SGR.frontOffice.EF.Entities.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) in c:\Users\ngranja\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SGR.frontoffice\EF\SGR.Context.cs:line 25
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715
```

Because that's where the context that was created by the Entity Data Model is:

```
namespace SGR.frontOffice.EF
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Entities()
            : base("name=defaultconnection")
        {
        }
...
```

How can i make it work? Or can someone point me on the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Are you using EF Code-First Approach?

Comment: It says that you started with model first or database first. If you want to start with an existing database and continue development with code first, look for "code first from database". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx